python problem with chained stdin to stdout
I want to have several python scripts to modify text files. For example, 'do1' accepts input from either stdin or a file, and sends output to either stdout or a file:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import select

fi = sys.stdin if select.select([ sys.stdin, ], [], [], 0.0 )[ 0 ] else None

ofname = None
for arg in sys.argv[ 1 : ]:
    if       fi is None: fi = open( arg )
    elif ofname is None: ofname = arg

if fi is None:
    print( '1 no stdin or input file' ) # 2 for do2
    exit( 1 )

if ofname is None:
    fo = sys.stdout
else:
    fo = open( ofname, 'w' )

for l in fi:
    fo.write( '1' ) # 2 for do2
    fo.write( l )

A second script do2 is the same but with '2 for 1' as in the comments. When I run this (on unix) I get various results:
$ echo hi | ./do1 | ./do2
2 no stdin or input file
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

or
$ echo hi | ./do1 | ./do2
2 no stdin or input file

or
$ echo hi | ./do1 | ./do2
21hi

What is going on here? I assume this is some kind of timing issue, with the the previous pipe disappearing before the next program can read it, but I don't know how to progress this.

Pipes aren't instantaneous. The second script doesn't have any input to read from the first script, so it immediately assumes there is no standard input. It's hard to distinguish between no standard input and a blocked read, so don't try.
Read from standard input unless you get an argument, and write to standard output unless you get an argument. Let the caller be responsibile for providing a readable file for standard input.
inf = None
out = None

for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    if inf is None:
        inf  = f
    elif outf is None:
        outf = f

fi = open(inf) if inf is not None else sys.stdin
fo = open(out, "w") if outf is not None else sys.stdout

for l in fi:
    fo.write( '1' ) # 2 for do2
    fo.write( l )


Huh, I had assumed that there would be some programmatic way to determine if there was a pipe to stdin. If not then I have to do as you say.
The problem with this approach is that the program cannot distinguish between being told about just an input file and being told about just an output file. I can get around that by using argument prefixes like -i and -o but its a little annoying.

The above code does not let me specify only an input pipe. I can only specify either (1) no files, (2) just infile or (3) infile and outfile.

(1) is handled by redirecting input from /dev/null, unless the output somehow depends on a distinction between no input file and an empty input file.

I am not sure if they are actual causes, but I suspect 2 potential sources of troubles

you are open-ing your files, but never close them, in python you should either use with open... (which will close file automatically for you) or close file yourself
buffering whilst not set in open does assume “Interactive” text files (files for which isatty() returns True) use line buffering. where line buffering means python does postpone writing until finding line ending, you need to flush if you want write happen earlier


Adding fi.close(); fo.close() to the end does not change the behaviour.

Adding fo.flush() before the close statements makes no difference either.

Changing:
fi = sys.stdin if select.select([ sys.stdin, ], [], [], 0.0 )[ 0 ] else None

to
fi = sys.stdin if not sys.stdin.isatty() else None

seems to work reliably.

Hmm this solution works okay with my example scripts but not with the real script I am writing at work!
